# Best possible way to search for a given value among N unsorted numbers

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

One of my friend has been asked with a question in an interview:

The best possible way to search for a given value among N unsorted numbers in a array.

Comment: [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), I would say.

Comment: what are "nos"  ?

Comment: numbers, probably

Comment: @Chris I wouldnt want to work for a company whose recruiter does not know how to properly pronounce the word "numbers" :P

Comment: C or C++? Pick one of them! And read [ask].

Comment: I know best way among M unsorted nos. How to do that among N I have no idea.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  For example, the C++ language has `std::find` and `std::sort`, which are not present in the C language.  First question I would ask the interviewer is the choice of language. :-)

Comment: @tobi303 my guess is that this was not the recruiters choice of words

Answer (score 3):

If the array is unsorted, you need to perform a linear scan of the list.  This examines (worst case) every element in the array.  Such a search is O(n).

Sorting won't help here, since the best sorts run in O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

If it was sorted I'd say [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), but for unsorted, just go with [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (unless the container you use has a member `find`; if it does, then use that as it is probably faster).

Answer (score 0):

It depends:
-if you just want to search a single value, the answer given by bush is enough.

-if you know what you want to perform repeated "query", it could be better to perform before some kind of preprocessing,in order to find fastly these value.If you want to know *only* if a value is contained in the array, you can use structures like hashset,bloom filter,etc..
In other cases,you would like to know also position of items inside the array. In this scenario,you can consider to use an hashmap